# How to simplify my if conditions using Boolean Logic?

Tags: boolean-algebra

My code:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if "_continue" in request.POST:
        if "PAN_ID" in request.POST and not change:
            try:
                data = Dematad.objects.filter(
                    Q(PAN1=obj.PAN_ID) | Q(PAN2=obj.PAN_ID) | Q(PAN3=obj.PAN_ID)
                ).get()
                
                obj.email= data.EMAIL1.strip() or data.EMAIL2.strip() or data.EMAIL3.strip() or None
                
                obj.full_name =  data.NAME
                
                obj.address =  ", ".join(
                        [data.AD1, data.AD2, data.AD3, data.AD4, data.PIN]
                    )
            except Dematad.DoesNotExist:
                    self.message_user(
                        request, "User created and saved. No data available in database."
                    )
                    
 
         
    if not change:
        obj.is_superuser = False
        obj.is_staff = True
        obj.set_password(User.objects.make_random_password(20))
```

​
return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

I want to simplify the code and thus tried to model the if conditions through logic. Consider the try, except block together as D

S1:  $A \implies ((B  \land \tilde C) \implies D)$

S2:  $ \tilde C \implies E $

How do I connect these statements? How do I simplify my if conditions?

EDIT:
By simplification I' m meaning to remove the inner block, or avoid nested if's. I want to know how can expressions be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't think you can combine or simplify because:

1. You don't have repeated expressions, so playing with different variables is not a good idea IMHO
2. We don't know if combining the if conditions would lead into a different program, so better a programmer should answer that question

Edit. [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28A+IMPLIES+%28%28B+%26%26+NOT%28C%29%29+IMPLIES+D%29%29+%26%26+%28%28NOT+C%29+IMPLIES+E%29) cannot reduce the combined expressions.

Comment: I have seen people compressing 10 line code to single line on codegolf. It must be possible but I don't know what will be the right channel to ask that.

Comment: It really depends on the code. You can have a code where you can apply [absorption law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_law), which is an equivalence, but it is weird to see it. Also, you don't have repeated expressions in one if statement.